# Effective C++: Item 41 - confusion about Implicit interfaces

Tags: c++, effective-c++

I am reading Effective C++, Item 41 with the title of **"Understanding implicit interfaces and compile-time polymorphism"**, It give this example and next an explanation but I don't understand this part.

```
template<typename T>
void doProcessing(T& w)
{
     if (w.size() > 10 && w != someNastyWidget) {
     ...
```

> ..., T must support a size member function, ....., But this member function need not return an integral type. It need not even return a numeric type. For that matter, it need not even return a type for which operator `>` is defined! All it needs to do is return an object of some type x such that there is an operator `>` that can be called with and object of type x and an int ...

Could you please explain what it is about and give more examples?

Comment: Which part of the explanation is unclear?

Comment: This is known as [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). `w.size()` doesn't need to be anything, just that `w.size() > 10` needs to be convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @UnholySheep from "For that matter, ..." to the end is quite vague.

Comment: i guess the author just wants to emphasize that while we have certain expectations when we see a `size()` (eg we assume it to return an integral type), all that is really necessary is that `size()` is such that this line compiles without errors

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that the `T::size()` function can return anything which can be compared (using `>`) to an `int` value.

---

Lets look at three examples:

1. Return an `int`:

   ```
   struct MyT
   {
       // Some stuff...

       int size()
       {
           return some_calculation_returning_int();
       }

       // Some more stuff...
   };
   ```
2. Return an object which can be converted to an `int`:

   ```
   struct MySizeType
   {
       // Some stuff...

       operator int()
       {
           return some_calculation_returning_int();
       }

       // Some more stuff...
   };

   struct MyT
   {
       // Some stuff...

       MySizeType size()
       {
           return MySizeType();
       }

       // Some more stuff...
   };
   ```
3. Return an object which can be compared with `>` to an `int`:

   ```
   struct MyOtherSizeType
   {
       // Some stuff...

       operator>(int other)
       {
           return some_calculation_returning_int() > other;
       }

       // Some more stuff...
   };

   struct MyT
   {
       // Some stuff...

       MyOtherSizeType size()
       {
           return MyOtherSizeType();
       }

       // Some more stuff...
   };
   ```

While it should be quite clear that the first variant can be used, the other two can *also* be used. That is because they, one way or another, returns something which can be compared to an `int` value.

If we "expand" the three variants:

1. `w.size() > 10` is simply like it is.
2. `w.size() > 10` will be `w.size().operator int() > 10`. Here the `MySizeType::operator int()` conversion function will be used to convert the `MySizeType` object to an `int` value that can be compared.
3. `w.size() > 10` will be `w.size().operator>(10)`. Here the `MyOtherType::operator>()` function will be used for the comparison itself.

**Reference**

1. [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)
2. [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: Is it possible if `it need not even return a type for wich operator> is defined!`?
I think this was the unclear part.

Comment: @Federico Case 2 has that property.

Comment: @Federico Added a few examples after your comment.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Didn't have that when the comment were posted.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I saw, I commented just to point out what the op wanted (maybe) to understand, I already `+1`ed your answer anyway ;)